# mysql joining empty rows?

Tags: sql, mysql

i have this query

```
SELECT cities.city, city_date.date_avail 
FROM cities, city_date 
WHERE city_date.city_id = cities.id;
```

but i would like the query to return all the cities from cities even if they dont have a city_date associated with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see OUTER JOINS ;) (RIGHT / LEFT / FULL)

```
SELECT cities.city, city_date.date_avail
FROM cities
LEFT OUTER JOIN city_date ON city_date.city_id = cities.id;
```